# What are the jars needed for only Spring-MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I need to run the Spring-MVC in my scratch project. At the same time i have minimum memory area to store all the jar files. So any body recommend me only need for the Spring-MVC not any other jar files. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

according to maven, spring-webmvc `3.1.2` need following jar:

- aopalliance-1.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar

things provided by servlet container (f.e. servlet-api) are left out.

Comment: You should probably note that he should not use commons logging but instead SLF4J. Spring even recommends not using or depending on it.

Comment: @AdamGent thx for the good advice. in case of a novice i usually conceale the existence of slf4j, because the api/impl dependencies in slf4j can be tricky to setup.

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No, one maven dependcy does nto equal one jar.

Comment: the answer makes only sence if he uses maven and helps him only if he runs `mvn dependency:tree`... why giving such a useless answer?