# Unable to add Spring MVC dependency to Maven Project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring Mvc.. I am trying to create a Maven Based Spring Mvc Demo..

The basic "hello world" Demo is working fine. It prints the "Hello World" when I hit "http://localhost:8080/SampleRestful/"

But, the moment I add `spring-webmvc` dependency to my pom.xml and run it on server, it throws the **Error 404** on hitting "http://localhost:8080/SampleRestful/".

Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.promact.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleRestful</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SampleRestful Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SampleRestful</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the error log :

```
    Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.8
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2016 21:14:13 UTC
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.8.0
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_92-b14
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\SpringWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\SpringWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\SpringWorkspace
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_92/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\webserver\ImageMagick;C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.8.1-Q16;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Python27;D:\Nishant\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;D:\Nishant\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ant 1.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ant 1.8\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin;C:\webserver\MySQL\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Users\nishant\Downloads\libs\depot_tools\;D:\Nishant\Android\android-ndk-r8e\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\gradle-2.1-all\gradle-2.1\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd3d58663c627ef\bin;D:\setups\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\setups\java\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Users\m\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\atom\bin;D:\setups\java\spring-tool-suite-3.8.2.RELEASE-e4.6.1-win32-x86_64\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.2.RELEASE;;.
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 835 ms
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.8
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [110] milliseconds.
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\SpringWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SampleRestful.xml
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SampleRestful' did not find a matching property.
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleRestful]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@3f797939]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@572b1df8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The directory specified by base and internal path [D:\SpringWorkspace\SampleRestful\target\m2e-wtp\web-resources]\[] does not exist.
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.checkType(DirResourceSet.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractFileResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractFileResourceSet.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal(DirResourceSet.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 16 more

Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor D:\SpringWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SampleRestful.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleRestful]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor D:\SpringWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\SampleRestful.xml has finished in 15 ms
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
Mar 24, 2017 12:19:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 632 ms
```

**I am unable to find the reason behind the issue. Please Help..!! :(**

Comment: are running from eclipse Run as-->Run on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC can't be used alone, it needs other dependecies like : Spring-core, Spring-context, Spring-beans and Spring-web.

If you want to start a new SpringMVC project I'll recommand you to do as follow (this is how I do when I start a new SpringMVC project):

1) Add Spring Tool Suite to Eclipse (go to "Help"(menu)->Eclipse Marketplace-> (in Find serch bar) enter "STS" and install it.

2) Then in Eclipse, go to File->Spring Legacy Project->Spring MVC Project (enter a project name), click next, enter a package name and finish.

You'll have a pre-configured Spring MVC project which works fine. I suggest you to change the versions of Java and other dependecies.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes I just found out that other dependencies like Spring-core, Spring-context, Spring-bean etc were required. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means, that Tomcat does not know what to do with the source attribute from context.
First thing first, you can't start mvc maven project with only one jar.
Add other DI, like spring core, and others to run  it: [What are the jars needed for only Spring-MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685579/what-are-the-jars-needed-for-only-spring-mvc)
You can change tomcat server configuration. Open the server view, double click on your server to open server configuration. Then click to activate "Publish module contents to separate XML files". Finally, restart your server and the problem will be fixed.
2nd thing that you can do, is to try with other version of tomcat. Update project, clean maven, build it and run after that.
Also if that doesn't help you.
This one is a great example of how to deploy your project on Tomcat server by using Maven's tomcat-maven-plugin: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/